# Warning C4278: 'GetCurrentDirectory': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the 'rename' qualifier

Tags: visual-c++, com, typelib

I'm migrating a VC++ 6.0 application to Visual studio 2008. I've fixed all the migration errors, now I'm fixing the warnings. The following warning occurs in almost 40 instances, Even after so much trial and errors and research in google, I'm not able to fix this warning.

Please find below an instance of the C42778 Error, If I get some help to fix the one below, I'll follow the same approach to fix the remaning 39 warnings.

> Warning C4278: 'GetCurrentDirectory': identifier in type library 'GCRComp.tlb' is already a macro; use the  'rename' qualifier

```
------Code snippet from ZipFile1.h -------

#import "GCRCOmp.tlb" rename_namespace("GCRTools") // C42778


------Code snippet from gcrcomp.tlh -------

Virtual HRESULT __stdcall raw_GetCurrentDirectory {
/*[out]*/ BSTR * dirname,
/*[out, retval]*/ VARIANT_BOOL * okStatus)=0;
virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_currentDirectory {
/*[out, retval]*/ BSTR * pVal)=0;


__declspec(property(get=GetcurrentDirectory))
_bstr_t currentDirectory;


VARIANT_BOOL GetCurrentDirectory (
BSTR * dirname);
_bstr_t GetcurrentDirectory ();

------Code snippet from gcrcomp.tli-------

inline VARIANT_BOOL IFtp1::GetCurrentDirectory(BSTR * dirname){
    VARIANT_BOOL _result = 0;
    HRESULT _hr = raw_GetCurrentDirectory(dirname, &_result);
    if(FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _result;
}

inline _bstr_t IFtp1::GetCurrentDirectory(){
    BSTR _result = 0;
    HRESULT _hr = get_currentDirectory(&_result);
    if (FAILED(_hr) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _bstr_t(result, false);
}
```

Any help to fix this warning is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The warning already tells you [what to do about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6zk74w.aspx).

Comment: Hi Hanse Passant. I really don't know how to fix this warning. I've already checked the link you've given and tried it, May be I'm wrongly using "rename". Can you please share the correct code, which would fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It because `GetCurrentDirectory` is already defined in Windows SDK. It is a part of ANSI/Unicode API conversion. The way to fix is undefined it before import `GCRCOmp.tlb`. Try this:

```cpp
#pragma push_macro("GetCurrentDirectory")
#undef GetCurrentDirectory
#import "GCRCOmp.tlb" rename_namespace("GCRTools")
#pragma pop_macro("GetCurrentDirectory")
```

Comment: That hides the warning, not the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code UltimaWeapon. It fixes the warning, But as per @Hans Passant I'm not sure if this fixes the problem or not.